# Creating Greek Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sharepoint

I heard a term "Greek Text" for dummy unintelligible text for testing in QA.

Is it a correct term? If yes, how do we create this data?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://www.lipsum.com/

Answer (score 5):

I think you are referring to [Lorem Ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).

There is a generator [here](http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html). Refreshing the page gives you new random text.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Lorem Ipsum you could also consider:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy sleeping dog.
```

...repeated as often as necessary.

That particular sentence is used because it holds every letter of the English alphabet. More for graphic design I suppose but still an option for dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a great generator, and offers "regular" latin greeking along with some more entertaining options. Pseudo German and Hillbilly are my personal favorites.

http://www.duckisland.com/GreekMachine.asp